# How to use tmux between local laptop and remote server

Tags: terminal, tmux, window, gnu-screen, session

I am currently in a VPN using RStudio which is installed on my local desktop to do some analysis.

However, to do analysis, I extract data from my database which is installed on a remote server.

What I currently do is

a) Connect to VPN

b) Login into the remote server

c) Port-forward the database connection (ssh -L 8890:localhost:8890 test) so that I can use the database client (`pgadmin`) in my laptop. My db runs at port 8890 in the server which I forward to 8890 locally.

d) Launch R studio from my local desktop

e) Connect to the database instance using the below details (using R code as shown below)

```
dbms = "postgresql" #Should be "sql server", "oracle", "postgresql" or "redshift"
user <- "test"
pw <- "test"
server <- "localhost/test"
port <- "8890"
connectionDetails <- createConnectionDetails(dbms=dbms, server=server, user=user, password=pw, schema=cdmSchema, port=port)
conn <- connect(connectionDetails)
```

Though the above works fine, the process gets aborted whenever there is an internet connection issue.

How can I use tmux in this setting to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something breaks the connection between your workstation and the remote server you have to re-establish the connection.  Tmux won't help with that.

If you have full access to the remote server you may be able to run your entire workload there, and any analysis you start on the remote server will continue to run even if your local workstation gets interrupted.

Not sure what your VPN rules are, but it might be easier to figure out why your connection keeps getting interrupted and fix that.

Comment: Thanks upvoted and accepted. Yes, now am running everything in remote server